# Pirush On Megilas Esther regarding the word "Melech"

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, megillat-esther, commentaries, drush

I remember seeing a book which explains how, b'derech Drash, every instance of the word "Melech" in Megilas Esther, as referring to Hashem.

Does anyone know the name of this sefer?

Comment: Are you asking for a book that states that every instance is referring to Hashem, or explains in each instance how it is referring to Hashem?

Comment: I've heard that this only applied to the word HaMelech, and only when not followed by the name Achashverosh.

Comment: @ypnypn The midrash in Megillah - Ester Rabba 3:10 (at least as quoted by the Gra) says it without any qualification.  Although it does say hamelech, not melech.  I'm not sure how common melech is in the megillah, anyways.

Comment: Are you thinking of sefer ילקוט מלכו של עולם?

Comment: @YEZ thanks for the source; I checked it up and it says clearly that it's only when not followed by Achashverosh.

Comment: @sam that seems to be correct, but I can't find it anywhere online, and I have checked hebrewbooks and otzar hachochmah.

Comment: Here it is http://yulib.mc.yu.edu:8000/cgi-bin/gw/chameleon?u1=1035&host=localhost+2222+DEFAULT&sessionid=VTLS&skin=portal&inst=consortium&submittheform=&usersrch=1&beginsrch=1&elementcount=3&function=INITREQ&search=KEYWORD&rootsearch=KEYWORD&lng=en&pos=1&t1=%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98+%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95+%D7%A9%D7%9C+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called שערי צבי - "Shaarey Tzvi" written by Rav Tzvi Rotter shlit"a (he is the son of the Shaaray Aharon). The book can be found [here](http://www.virtualgeula.com/Stock/Books/Show/10991) and can be partially viewed [here](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?171108).

Hat tip to sam regarding another book with the same premise, ילקוט מלכו של עולם - "Yalkut Malko Shel Olam", information about it can be found [here](http://yulib.mc.yu.edu:8000/cgi-bin/gw/chameleon?sessionid=2014021310531424968&skin=portal&lng=en&inst=consortium&host=localhost%2b2222%2bDEFAULT&patronhost=localhost%202222%20DEFAULT&search=AUTHID&searchid=1&function=CARDSCR&sourcescreen=COPVOLSCR&pos=1&totalitems=1&itempos=1&rootsearch=SCAN&histselect=1).

Comment: The final link is dead. Can someone update it?