What is the deeper explanation of this passage in Iggeret Hakodesh (According to true Kabbalah or Chassidic explanation)
BH
Hi, so I started to read the Ramban's Iggeret Hakodesh's chapter on the intention of union trying to understand a  specific section from of it. It says..

Ben Azzai was sitting and learning and a fire started to burn around him.

Ramban quotes another example in the Iggeret and says that

similarly Rabbi Eliezer was sitting and explaining the words of Torah and light was beaming from him like Moses our teacher peace be upon him.

So he says at the end

These things have one meaning to them. Know that though a spring of
water naturally flows from a high place to a lower one there is a
power capable of raising the water to a different place higher than
where it has flowed from. It is also known to the masters of Kabbalah
that thought of man comes from the spiritual source of the rational
soul which is drawn from the upper spheres and there is a power in the
thought to expand and rise and reach its highest source and upon
arriving at its source it can cleave to the Mystery of Elyon, that from there, She and He flow and become one. And when the
thought returns below from above it becomes similar to a single ray
and that supernal light is drawn downward and the power of the thought
that draws it downward and the light of the luminescence is drawn down
and spreads in that place where the person is thinking.

So what does it mean "Know that though a spring of water naturally flows from a high place to a lower one there is a power capable of raising the water to a different place higher than where it has flowed from." What is this analogy and what is it analogous to really? What is the power hes talking about in the analogy and what is it reffering to?
What does it mean "It is also known to the masters of Kabbalah that thought of man comes from the spiritual source of the rational soul which is drawn from the upper spheres" What is the source of this? Also it seems to imply that the spiritual source of the rational soul causes the thoughts to become somthing of its own (meaning the spiritual source of the rational soul is the one who has the dominion of the the thought it self to create it etc also seems like the spiritual source of the rational soul also somehow  draws the thought from the upper spheres as well.
If so though what does it mean "and there is a power in the thought to expand and rise and reach its highest source? How is this possihle as it was just said that the thought of man comes from the spiritual source of the rational soul as is someone really going to say that the thought some how gets disconnected that it has its own power to rise up to its source on it's own?
Also when it said earlier that the thought of man comes from the spiritual source of the rational soul which is drawn from the upper spheres what is the spiritual source of the rational soul really? What spheres is he speaking about and where are the spheres located?
And then it says "and upon arriving at its source it can adhere to the upper secret from where it came from and she the thought and the thinker become one." So who is the thinker is it the man, Hashem, the spiritual root of the rational soul, the upper spheres or is the thought it self?
Finaly it says "And when the thought returns below from above it becomes similar to a single ray and that supernal light is drawn downward.."
In essence, How come it rises up and then down? How is this thought created Who creates it? How does it go up to a level higher than where it came from? How to make it go to a level higher than it came from? How does it go down again? How come it goes down again? Is the power to bring it up also have to put effort to bring it down or does it just automatically go down? How come he speaks about the thought as it's independent? Also Does all this have something to do with the subconsious?
Picture of the part from the Safer:



@RabbiKaii Please see my posted answer. You might reconsider your downvote.

Equating Kabbalah and Chassidut isn’t a good idea. They share some aspects, but they must be kept distinct, or many problematic misunderstandings of Kabbalah can occur.

@Qwertrl strongly recommend: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/4631998/jewish/On-the-Essence-of-Chassidus.htm

Thank you, so much!

In order to keep the length of this answer manageable, the effort will  be to stick with the allegory used by the Ramban.
He is comparing the analog, (the intellect שכל (the intellectual aspect of soul), meaning השכליות, which is comprised of the four aspects, or brains called: Keter כתר, Wisdom חכמה, Understanding בינה and applied knowledge דעת), to the allegory, (to a Wellspring (of living water) מעין מים חיים.) That Mayim Chayim מים חיים is a Notarikon for Brains מח meaning מוחין.
Like is observed with all water, one aspect is its natural tendency or behavioral trait to flow from a higher elevation to a lower elevation.
So too with the analog, the intellect. The higher, more refined aspects of intellect flow from higher to lower, from Keter to Chochmah to Binah to Da'at.
But the source (המקור of the Living Water) is the Wellspring, itself. The Wellspring המעין is in the Earth בתוך הארץ.
That הארץ is linguistically related to Supernal Will הרצון העליון. That רצון relates to the Earth and עליון is referring to G-d's feminine name צלמו, the Queen of Heaven (which is gematria 166. That עליון equals צלמו.).
That the earth הארץ surrounds (meaning it is מקיף היינו סובב to) the source המעין. And מעין which is gematria 820, (when counting the final Nun as 700,) alludes the Great Name (שמה רבא) mentioned in Kaddish, like is found in Yechezkel 36:23.

וְקִדַּשְׁתִּ֞י אֶת־שְׁמִ֣י הַגָּד֗וֹל

That וקדשתי is also gematria 820. This Great Name is also alluded to in Esther 9:32.

וּמַאֲמַ֣ר אֶסְתֵּ֔ר קִיַּ֕ם דִּבְרֵ֥י הַפֻּרִ֖ים הָאֵ֑לֶּה וְנִכְתָּ֖ב בַּסֵּֽפֶר׃

That ונכתב בספר, which is equated with מאמר אסתר, is also gematria 820. That what is written comes via the Queen.
And it should be noted that the gematria of מעין when including the kollel for the word is 821, which is gematria אחשורוש, the King of Megillat Esther.
That like Ramban quoted in your question states, From the Mystery of Elyon, She and He flow and become one.
שמשם (סוד העליון) נמשכת ונעשית היא והוא דבר אחד
That the Living Water מים חיים flows upward from its source in Supernal Will המעין שבארץ to be revealed in this corporeal, material world עולם הזה הגשמי והחומרי. This pertains to the Kabbalistic principle of Returning Light אור חוזר.
And in this context the following linked answer is related and worth reading:
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/141306/7303
For a detailed discussion of this subject, see the beginning of volume one from ספר המאמרים בשעה שהקדימו תרע״ב by the fifth Lubavitcher Rebbe, Rabbi Shalom Dovber

@RabbiKaii You aren't reading carefully enough. מעין is an allegory to the "source" of Living Water, meaning the source of intellect. The source of water is not the water. The "source" of intellect isn't the intellect. The source of intellect is Ratzon, "Will". The Wellspring, (which is in the Earth) is the allegory of Will. The analog of water is intellect, meaning Mochin מוח מ״ים ח״יים. That the Mochin are Sechel שכל.

@RabbiKaii To emphasize, Mushel and Nimshel, Allegory and analog. A model (an allegory, a mushel) which represents something real, it's analog (Nimshel).

Thank you so much

You’re welcome David. I hope it helped you understand. If you accept it as the correct answer, please don’t forget to mark it so. Only blessings for good!

You know I'm very interested on applying this Idea where you can get to the level of completley uniting with hashem and then bring down the light. Correct me if I'm wrong this happens all the time when we do Amida right? Like when davening were first in Assiya then Yetzira then Beriya then Atzilut then after we have to bring all the light from that world down here. Although how do you actully know this is happening?

Like also in this question the person is able to get to a level higher than where the water so to say came from so how to actually apply this when actually davening so you know your actually bringing down the light?

@David Bringing down the light from the Amidah is what follows in the text of the Kaddish Shalem and the Aleinu prayer which completes the prayer service. Look carefully at the content of these two prayers for the answer to your question.

What if your praying alone?

@David If you mean in regard to Kaddish, it really depends upon your minhag.There are traditions that still have a preserved text of what is called Kaddish d’Yachid for an individual who is praying alone. Ideally, you would want to make efforts to recite in the general proper time for wherever you are geographically speaking. The Aleinu prayer doesn’t require a minyan.
